# Cannot use string offset as an array - do I need to unserialize in foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting this error in logs:

> [Mon Feb 08 22:16:08 2016] [error] [client 2.125.15.96] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/addons/abandoned_cart_extended/controllers/backend/ac.php on line 43, referer: /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list

Which I think is $product['product_id']

When I do a print_r on the $products I get this this console: http://pastebin.com/QuTJzMX8

It's the cart data I need which I think if I'm not mistaken is serialized? I need to be able to use the data I get back from the query and loop through the items. The data in the database field is stored like it returns a:2:{i:1217356819;a:24:{s:10:\"product_id\";i: etc...

PHP

```
$acId = $_REQUEST['id'];

$products = db_get_fields("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
fn_print_r($products);
//$products = unserialize($products);

if(count($products)>0){

  $shippingCost = db_get_field("SELECT shipping FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
  $tax = db_get_field("SELECT tax FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
  $orderTotal = db_get_field("SELECT order_total FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
  $email = db_get_field("SELECT email FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
  $firstName = db_get_field("SELECT first_name FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
  $LastName = db_get_field("SELECT last_name FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);


  $sum=0;
  //echo $products;
  if (!empty($products)) {

    foreach ($products as $product) {
      $text .='
        <tr>
          <td><a  href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'?dispatch=products.view&product_id='.$product['product_id'].'"> <img title="" height="120" width="120" alt="" src="'.$product['main_pair']['detailed']['image_path'].'"></a></td>
          <td><a href="#" style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['product'].'</a><a href="#">&nbsp;<i></i></a><div style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;"> CODE: <span>'.$product['product_code'].'<!--product_code_update_2512012004--></span> </div></td>
          <td style=" text-align:center;"><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">$</span><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['price'].'</span> </td>
          <td><div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;width: 56px;"><input type="text" disabled value="'.$product['amount'].'" size="3"  style="border:1px solid #c2c9d0; box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; border-radius:3px; float: left;height: 33px;text-align: center;width: 36px;"></div></td>
          <td style="font-size:14px;  font-weight:bold; color:#333; text-align:center; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;"><span>$</span><span stye=" color:#000;">'.$product['price']*$product['amount'].'</span> </td>
        </tr>';
      $sum =$sum+$product['price']*$product['amount'];
    }
  }
}
```

I just tried something I saw on another Stack question but did not help, however I added `fn_print_r` for each as you see below and the result in console, so maybe this might help.

```
$productsFetch = db_get_field("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
fn_print_r($productsFetch);

$productsArray = unserialize($productsFetch);
fn_print_r($productsArray);

$products = var_export($productsArray);
fn_print_r(var_export($productsArray));
```

1st print_r is the a:2 stuff, 2nd shows false and 3rd is null

[image]

Comment: try with serialize and see what happen. but what returns `db_get_fields` ? If it returns a db object, maybe you can try to fetch rows. Show `db_get_fields` code

Comment: I tried with db_get_field and also done a few other bits to try and debug, let me update question with what i just done.

Comment: I just updated with what extra bits i added to print and also screenshot of console log that im getting back. Hope you can help as been stuck on this for so many hours over past 2 days haha

Comment: If i use fn_get_fields or fn_get_array i get a different returned result of course, but i get i just need to get that serialized data from cart field.. dont know, all new to me :)

Comment: can you show `db_get_fields` please? (copy-and-paste, not screenshot). Maybe there's a easy solution viewing this code....

Comment: Yep, give me a few mins.

Comment: Its an ajax response from a PHP controller so cool if i copy and paste from  whats printed in console?

Comment: there are php commands in console? if yes, ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102942/discussion-between-james-and-fusion3k).

Comment: Literally just worked it out with fusion3k and crazy how simple it was... especially after me spending so long trying to resolve but just needed to add stripslashes so: unserialize(stripslashes($productsFetch[0])); - @fusion3k if you want to post an Answer ill mark valid and thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your *$products* variable, as presented on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/QuTJzMX8) has this structure:

```
array(
    array(
        "serialised data"
    )
)
```

So, to get to the inner data, add this statement just after you have checked that *$products* is not empty:

```
$products = unserialize($products[0][0]);
```

If I `print_r($products)` after that, I get:

```
Array
(
    [1217356819] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 372
            [product_code] => 16002
            [product] => Acoustic Sofa - Eco Weave
            [amount] => 1
            [product_options] => Array
                (
                    [365] => 732
                )

            [price] => 249
            [stored_price] => N
            [main_pair] => Array
                (
                    [pair_id] => 417
                    [image_id] => 0
                    [detailed_id] => 1513
                    [position] => 0
                    [detailed] => Array
                        (
                            [image_path] => http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/1/Acoustic-eco-weave.jpg?t=1454562784
                            [alt] => 
                            [image_x] => 1500
                            [image_y] => 1500
                            [http_image_path] => http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/1/Acoustic-eco-weave.jpg?t=1454562784
                            [https_image_path] => https://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/1/Acoustic-eco-weave.jpg?t=1454562784
                            [absolute_path] => /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/images/detailed/1/Acoustic-eco-weave.jpg
                            [relative_path] => detailed/1/Acoustic-eco-weave.jpg
                        )

                )

            [extra] => Array
                (
                    [product_options] => Array
                        (
                            [365] => 732
                        )

                    [unlimited_download] => N
                )

            [stored_discount] => N
            [company_id] => 1
            [amount_total] => 1
            [options_type] => P
            [exceptions_type] => F
            [modifiers_price] => 0
            [is_edp] => N
            [edp_shipping] => N
            [discount] => 0
            [promotions] => Array
                (
                )

            [tax_summary] => Array
                (
                    [included] => 22.64
                    [added] => 0
                    [total] => 22.64
                )

            [base_price] => 249
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                )

            [display_price] => 249
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [rate_type] => P
                            [rate_value] => 10.000
                            [price_includes_tax] => Y
                            [regnumber] => 60499021423
                            [priority] => 0
                            [tax_subtotal] => 22.64
                            [description] => GST
                        )

                )

        )

    [2512012004] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 337
            [product_code] => 8001
            [product] => 300 Litres of PREMIUM Microbead filling
            [amount] => 1
            [product_options] => Array
                (
                )

            [price] => 79
            [stored_price] => N
            [main_pair] => Array
                (
                    [pair_id] => 1238
                    [image_id] => 0
                    [detailed_id] => 2334
                    [position] => 0
                    [detailed] => Array
                        (
                            [image_path] => http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/300-filling-1.jpg?t=1402299012
                            [alt] => 
                            [image_x] => 1500
                            [image_y] => 1500
                            [http_image_path] => http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/300-filling-1.jpg?t=1402299012
                            [https_image_path] => https://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/300-filling-1.jpg?t=1402299012
                            [absolute_path] => /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/images/detailed/2/300-filling-1.jpg
                            [relative_path] => detailed/2/300-filling-1.jpg
                        )

                )

            [extra] => Array
                (
                    [product_options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [unlimited_download] => N
                )

            [stored_discount] => N
            [company_id] => 1
            [amount_total] => 1
            [options_type] => P
            [exceptions_type] => F
            [modifiers_price] => 0
            [is_edp] => N
            [edp_shipping] => N
            [discount] => 0
            [promotions] => Array
                (
                )

            [tax_summary] => Array
                (
                    [included] => 7.18
                    [added] => 0
                    [total] => 7.18
                )

            [base_price] => 79
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 37
                    [1] => 32
                )

            [display_price] => 79
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [rate_type] => P
                            [rate_value] => 10.000
                            [price_includes_tax] => Y
                            [regnumber] => 60499021423
                            [priority] => 0
                            [tax_subtotal] => 7.18
                            [description] => GST
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and then continue with the `foreach` statement.

### 64 / 32 bit issue:

I found that the code worked for me on a 64-bit PHP installation, but not on a 32-bit one. There the `unserialize` failed without error message.

I found the cause to be in the key value of the second top-level array element in the above data. That key value is 2512012004. On 32-bit PHP installations the value of [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max) is lower than that: 2512012004, and so the unserialization fails.

On [eval.in](https://eval.in/515291) (32 bit) I put code that uses the data you provided, but that code does one replace on the data, in order to make this number smaller. Then it successfully unserializes the data and prints the resulting array. Check it out.

Of course, you then end up with a wrong key value (if that is important to you).

#### Conclusion

See if you can move to a 64 installation of PHP.

Comment: Getting 500 internal error in console, and in log says: [Mon Feb 08 22:59:09 2016] [error] [client 2.125.15.96] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/addons/abandoned_cart_extended/controllers/backend/ac.php on line 23, referer: /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list - line 23 being the unserialize part you suggested :( any ideas? and thanks for your help!

Comment: That was with fn_get_field but when i changed back to fn_get_fields just rereturned nothing (no 500 error) but also nothing in logs at all...

Comment: Can you please look here: i put image url to result in there as well: http://pastebin.com/PitJBRRj

Comment: Updated my answer: your problem is most probably related to a too-large integer in the data that your PHP installation cannot handle.

Comment: Literally just worked it out with fusion3k and crazy how simple it was... especially after me spending so long trying to resolve but just needed to add stripslashes so: unserialize(stripslashes($productsFetch[0]));

Comment: I am totally surprised by that, because the data you provided on pastebin has no backlashes and when I compare `stripslashes($products[0][0]) == $products[0][0])` it tells me they are the same. Also, I would like to know which key you got for the second array entry with key 2512012004 after unserializing. It is on pastebin, and I would want to make sure you got that index. All I can say is that what I answered worked for me with the data you provided. Anyway, I am glad to hear you solved the issue.